# Citizenship for a UK born child from EEA parents after 5 years

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, eu-citizens, children

These are the things I know:

- Children born in the UK by EEA parents before they obtained PR status are not British Citizens, but once the parents obtain the status they can register to become one.
- Children born in the UK by EEA parents after they obtained PR status are British Citizens.

Getting PR status is supposedly automatic after excercising treaty rights for five years. However getting proof of this [takes supposedly a long time](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/nov/30/eu-citizens-in-uk-home-office-residency-applications-right-to-remain-before-brexit-talks) as there is a huge backlog of PR applications yet to be processed.

So what happens to children who were born after the parents obtained PR status but before they get the proper paperwork about it. Are they British citizens? If yes, how to prove this to obtain a British passport for them?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the paperwork you need to send to the Home Office to obtain the citizenship for the child allows you to also submit the PR paperwork if you haven't gotten it yet, meaning one they accept it your child will get the Citizenship, and you will get the PR status at the same time